# dotnet compiler error while publishing f# project

Tags: asp.net, f#, .net-core

I am trying to publish a dotnet core 2.0.0 (release version) project from command line.
I am getting an error as below.

EXEC(1,1): error CS8301: Invalid name for a preprocessing symbol; '' is not a valid identifier [C:\Work\FloAppGit\FloAppStpl\FloMa
nufacturer\FloManufacturer.fsproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation\2.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsof
t.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.targets(60,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" exec --runt
imeconfig "C:\Work\FloAppGit\FloAppStpl\FloManufacturer\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\FloManufacturer.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "C:
\Work\FloAppGit\FloAppStpl\FloManufacturer\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\FloManufacturer.deps.json" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFa
llbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation\2.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilat
ion.dll" @"obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation.rsp"" exited with code 1. [C:\Work\FloAppGit\Flo
AppStpl\FloManufacturer\FloManufacturer.fsproj]

My project file is as follows.

```
<Project Sdk="FSharp.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
<PropertyGroup>
   <EnableDefaultCompileItems>False</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
   <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.0</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="Controllers/*.fs" />
   <Compile Include="FloLogger.fs" />
   <Compile Include="Restful.fs"/>
   <Compile Include="AppSettingsHelper.fs" />
   <Compile Include="DataRecords/BusinessRecords.fs"/> 

   <Compile Include="DAL/ManufacturerDAL.fs"/>
   <Compile Include="DAL/ItemManufacturerDAL.fs"/>


   <Compile Include="BAL/ItemManufacturerBAL.fs"/>
   <Compile Include="BAL/ManufacturerBAL.fs"/>

   <Compile Include="Manufacturer.fs" />
   <Compile Include="ItemManufacturer.fs" />

   <Compile Include="Startup.fs" />
   <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
 </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Core" Version="4.1.*" />
   <PackageReference Include="FSharp.NET.Sdk" Version="1.0.*" PrivateAssets="All" />
   <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.8" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="RavenDB.Client" Version="4.0.0-beta-40016" />
   <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="5.1.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Suave" Version="2.0.3.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Suave.AspNetCore" Version="0.3.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Suave.DotLiquid" Version="2.0.3" />
   <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

Please help me resolve this issue as I am stuck.

Comment: Seems very similar to https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1364 , but I think that is supposed to be fixed in netcore 2.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue by commenting these lines in the project file.

```
 <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Core" Version="4.1.*" />
 <PackageReference Include="FSharp.NET.Sdk" Version="1.0.*" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

Also I had to change the header of the project file like this.

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Delete the obj and bin folders. Do a dotnet clean then dotnet restore.
I was able to publish the code successfully for dotnet core 2.0.0 release version.